# aws: Failed to add new API in cloud logic, mobile hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-mobilehub

When I try create new api or import api from api gateway in cloud logic, mobile hub aws, I get this error:

> Failed to update project: Unable to deploy resources because the deployments S3 bucket is missing.

There is deployments folder in s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mobile Hub project uses a project-specific S3 bucket to deploy artifacts to AWS Lambda and Amazon API Gateway. This bucket is created when the project is created or if that didn't happen, then an attempt will be made to create the bucket each time you update any project configuration in Mobile Hub. There are a number of reasons creation of the bucket could have failed. For example, you could have a DENY policy in place which is preventing the MobileHub_Service_Role from having the appropriate permissions to create the S3 bucket. Or, you could be at your maximum limit of buckets (default limit is 100, but you can contact customer support to get the limit increased). If the bucket exists, then you will see it on the Resources page in Mobile Hub (with "deployments" in the name).

If you're not able to resolve this based on the information above, then please contact customer support and give them your account ID and someone from the Mobile Hub team will look up the reason for the S3 bucket creation failure in the service logs.

Comment: Thank you. I create api using cloud logic, mobile hub. Added 2-3 paths with Lambda functions and then I added a few more using api gateway. The s3 folder contains Lambda functions which were added from mobile hub and not from Api gateway. Is this causing the error?

Comment: No, you should be able to add paths anywhere. If you're still getting errors, please contact customer support and provide your account ID and the team will track down the issue.